# Load imageview in android crashes app

Tags: android, imageview, out-of-memory

Hi I have a layout which has 3 images,I can load the same image in all the 3 imageviews and it works fine but when I try to load 3 different images the app crashes and give OOM error.I have read about this problem and I know the problem is due to the image large size,but I still couldn't find solution.

xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:background="@color/bkgColor"
android:weightSum="3"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cap1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/shot2"    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cap2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/third" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cap3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/half" />
```

Logcat:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{wedidit.noname/wedidit.noname.Capacity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at wedidit.noname.Capacity.onCreate(Capacity.java:17)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at wedidit.noname.Capacity.onCreate(Capacity.java:17) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24300012 byte allocation with 8388512 free bytes and 12MB until OOM
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:747)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:568)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3747)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3620)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:151)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:136)
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:435) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at wedidit.noname.Capacity.onCreate(Capacity.java:17) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389) 
10-14 16:02:01.520 10670-10670/wedidit.noname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184) 
10
```

Comment: if you read about it and know its due to the image size so why dont you resize the image?

Comment: the codes I found does not work for me and I hoped I would fine here a more explained code.

Comment: Post the possible code from `PhoneLayoutInflater` class

Comment: Dont have this class in my project,i have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try to apply the Instruction provided here to load large bitmaps with memory efficiency . 
The idea is to scale down the bitmap if its size is too big .

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) when I need to work with images on android. Try it and you will love it!